# What is wrong with this use of std::unique_ptr that gives invalid pointer error?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Here is the code:

https://onlinegdb.com/BksirkDxw

I copy the same code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class cA{
    public: 
    cA(){}
    ~cA(){}
};
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<cA> qq(new cA[200]);
    
    cout << "OK" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
OK                                                                                                                    
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000014f4c28 ***                                               
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Just doing new, and nothing more interesting.

Why do I get invalid pointer error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior. You're specifying the `std::unique_ptr` as containing single object, but you're initializing it with an array.
You should specify the template argument as array; otherwise `std::unique_ptr` would try to call `delete` but not `delete[]` to destroy the object and deallocate the memory.

```
std::unique_ptr<cA[]> qq(new cA[200]);
```